# Magento 2 get order ID before sending to payment gateway in checkout page phtml?

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, magento2, magento2.2, getid3

How to get the current order id before sending the order I know how to get the last order id but I am getting the current order id before submitting the order and I am working on my own module

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Magento 2 events for this. Not sure if `sales_order_place_before` `sales_order_place_after` is best suited for your needs, but the code goes something like this:

In your module's `events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="observername" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\YourClass" />
    </event>
</config>
```

and in YourClass.php

```
<?php
namespace NBG\Mailtrigger\Observer;
class YourClass implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
        // your logic...
    }
}
```